# How to install ArrowChat in laravel website

Tags: laravel, chat, integration

I've been stuck integrating arrowchat with laravel.
I purchased arrowchat and by install documentation, I did.
But I can't install.
Is it possible to integrate arrowchat to laravel?
I think it's possible.
If possible, how to do that?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. What errors/issues are you running into?

Comment: I am trying to install, so I did install page (/arrowchat).
In general php website, I can see it is working well when I enter install step.
But when I try that in  laravel, I can't see install page, I see only empty page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, we should bootstrap Laravel in the integration file of Arrowchat.

So the start of the integration.php should be start like this:

```
$base_path = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
require_once($base_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php');
require_once($base_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php');
$app = require_once($base_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app.php');

try {
    $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());

    $id = $app['encrypter']->decrypt($_COOKIE[$app['config']['session.cookie']]);

     $app['session']->driver()->setId($id);
     $app['session']->driver()->start();

} catch(\Exception $ex) {
}


function get_user_id() {
    $userid = NULL;
    global $app;

    $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());

    $id = $app['encrypter']->decrypt($_COOKIE[$app['config']['session.cookie']]);
    $app['session']->driver()->setId($id);
    $app['session']->driver()->start();

    if($app['auth']->user()!= NULL){
         $userid = $app['auth']->user()->id;
    }

    return $userid;
}
```

[Source](http://andrasgalli.com/2017/03/11/arrowchat-integration-to-laravel-5-3/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply
First of all, I can't find integration.php in arrowchat source.
I use arrowchat v2.2